# Random walk with barriers: estimate time since the appearance of a barrier

Tags: random-walk, stopping-times

I am trying to evaluate whether using the Brownian motion equations (random walk) in presence of a barrier it is possible to estimate the time of appearance of a barrier (permeable or not) in a system.

I am not a mathematician, but I was wondering whether someone has experience on that and if this is mathematically feasible.